# What is the usage of Angular error Vs hasError?

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms

<span *ngIf="myReativeForm.get('userDetails.email').errors['required']">This is required field

Vs

<span *ngIf="myReativeForm.get('userDetails.email').hasError('required')">This is required field

Answer (score 1):

`errors` returns an object if there is any error or null

`hasError()` returns a boolean on a given validation

With `errors` you don't need to know about available errors and you can loop over them.

Answer (score 1):

I have made this silly example component:

Template:

```html
<input type="text" [formControl]="form">

<span *ngIf="form.errors?.['myError']">errors shows the span</span>
<span *ngIf="form.hasError('myError')">hasError shows the span</span>

{{ 'hasError value ' + form.hasError('myError')}}
<br>
{{ 'errors value ' + form.errors?.['myError']}}
```

TypeScript:

```js
@Component({
  standalone: true,
  imports: [CommonModule, ReactiveFormsModule],
  templateUrl: './my-component.component.html',
})
export class MyComponentComponent {
  public form = new FormControl<any>('', (control: AbstractControl) => {
    const numberOfLetters = (control as FormControl).value.length;
    return numberOfLetters === 2 ? { myError: 0} : null;
  });
```

This code never shows the spans.

**hasError** case always returns `false` and it prints: `hasError value false`.

**errors** case returns

- `null` when numberOfLetters is not 2 and prints `errors value null`
- `0` when numberOfLetters is 2 and prints `errors value 0`

If the validator would return:

```js
return numberOfLetters === 2 ? { myError: 'truthy' } : null;
```

Then when numberOfLetters is not 2 it is the same case than before. There is no error and spans are not shown.

And when numberOfLetters is 2, **hasError** case returns `true` and **errors** case returns `'truthy'`.

So my suggestion is to use

```html
<span *ngIf="form.errors?.['myError'] !== null">
  errors shows the span if comparing to not null or particular value
</span>
```

That way even if the value of `myError` is falsy, it still would show the span.

Looking at the code of [hasError](https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/main/packages/forms/src/model/abstract_model.ts#L1263) you can see that it just double negates the errors. The advantage of `hasError` is that it allows you to pass a second argument to validate a subformcontrol:

```html
<span *ngIf="myReativeForm.hasError('required', 'userDetails.email')">
  Some feedback message
</span>
```

or:

```html
<span *ngIf="myReativeForm.hasError('required', ['userDetails', 'email'])">
  Some feedback message
</span>
```

### Old answer

In the example you gave, I don´t see any difference, but you should use

```html
<span *ngIf="myReativeForm.get('userDetails.email').hasError('required')">
```

#### Why?

Case 1:

```js
myReativeForm.get('userDetails.email').errors['customError']
```

It might produce a null exception if errors is null. Better you should use

```js
myReativeForm.get('userDetails.email').errors?.customError
```

But even if errors is not null and customError is present, you are accesing to its value, and it could be something coercing to falsy. Then your span won´t be shown even the customError is present.

Case 2:

```html
<span *ngIf="myReativeForm.get('userDetails.email').hasError('customError')">
```

It will always return true or false. If the customError is present, true, if it isn´t, false.

Comment: could you please give an example of "something coercing to falsy" for the mentioned case, please?

Comment: Actually I did a test and my answer is wrong. If the value is falsy, both errors and hasError don´t show the span. I have updated the answer.